# pandas build matrix of row by row comparisons

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two dataframes, a (10,2) and a (4,2) and I am looking for a faster/more pythonic way to compare them row by row.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([range(10),range(2,12)])
x = x.transpose()
y = pd.DataFrame([[5,8],[2,3],[5,5]])
```

I'd like to build a comparison matrix (10,3) that shows which of the rows in the first dataframe fit the following requirements in the second dataframe. the x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MFd9.jpg) value must be >= the y[0] value and the x[0] value must be <= the y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MFd9.jpg) value.  In reality, the data are dates, but for simplicity I have just used integers to make this example easier to follow.  We're testing for overlap in time periods, so the logic shows that there must be some overlap in the periods of the respective tables.

```
arr = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)), dtype=bool)
for xrow in x.index:
    for yrow in y.index:
        if x.loc[xrow,1] >= y.loc[yrow,0] and x.loc[xrow,0] <= y.loc[yrow,1]:
            arr[xrow,yrow] = True
arr
```

[image]

The brute force approach above is too slow.  Any suggestions for how I could vectorize this or do some sort of transposed matrix comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `x`, `y` to NumPy arrays and then extend dimensions with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), which would bring in [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) when performing the same operations. Thus, all those comparisons and the output boolean array would be created in a vectorized fashion. The implementation would look like this -

```
X = np.asarray(x) 
Y = np.asarray(y)
arr = (X[:,None,1] >= Y[:,0]) & (X[:,None,0] <= Y[:,1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [207]: x = pd.DataFrame([range(10),range(2,12)])
     ...: x = x.transpose()
     ...: y = pd.DataFrame([[5,8],[2,3],[5,5]])
     ...: 

In [208]: X = np.asarray(x) 
     ...: Y = np.asarray(y)
     ...: arr = (X[:,None,1] >= Y[:,0]) & (X[:,None,0] <= Y[:,1])
     ...: 

In [209]: arr
Out[209]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Perfect - I knew that there was some way to use broadcasting, I'll have to do a little research to understand how you're combining those, but this works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @flyingmeatball Broadcasting is the best thing that has happened with NumPy, if you ask me:) So, do do explore it!

Comment: Quick random aside, how do you format your output from ipython notebook so nicely to fit into a SO response?  It always takes me forever to format mine before posting.

Comment: @flyingmeatball You mean the sample run or the code itself?

Comment: The sample run, sorry.

Comment: @flyingmeatball Well I am on Spyder, so it's as good as right click and then for copying it has two options - 1) Simple Copy and 2) Copy raw text. I do the raw copy text thing, it's just super-handy!